# Select elements of an array inside an array

Tags: java, arrays, mongodb

This is the object in the database

```js
{ 
    "_id" : { "$oid" : "53a9ce071e24a7a0a4bef03a"} ,
    "name" : "name4" , 
    "sections" : [ 
        { 
            "id" : "sectionId1" , 
            "subs" : [ 
                { "name" : "name1" , "enable" : true} , 
                { "name" : "name2" , "enable" : false} , 
                { "name" : "name3" , "enable" : true}
            ]
        }, 
        { 
            "id" : "sectionId2", 
            "subs" : [ 
                { "name" : "name1" , "enable" : true} , 
                { "name" : "name5" , "enable" : false} , 
                { "name" : "name6" , "enable" : true}
            ]
        }, 
        { "id" : "sectionId3"}
    ]
}
```

and this is my code :

```java
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
query.append("name", "name4");
query.append("sections", new BasicDBObject(
    "$elemMatch", new BasicDBObject("id", "sectionId2")
));
query.append("sections.subs", new BasicDBObject(
    "$elemMatch", new BasicDBObject("name", "name1")
));
```

I am trying to access the 'name1' in 'subs' of 'sectionId2'. But my query returns the sub in 'sectionId1'. I am having this problem only for 'name1'. I can access 'name2', 'name3' etc without any errors because they are unique.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does "access" mean to you? Are you trying to "find" this in a query or "update" the selected element in the array? In either case the positional `$` only returns the "outer" array position in the match. What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

It may be because of the $elemMatch that you are using, the $elemMatch projection returns only the first matching element from the array. [see it here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/)